# Update gradle from 1.3 to 2.1.0 and get error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, instant-run

In order to use InstantRun, I update the gradle from 1.3.1 to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-rc1'` and get this error

```
Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api
```

how to solve it? I just wanna use InstantRun.

Comment: Android Build System com.android.tools.build.gradle:2.0.0 onwards need gradle-2.10 to run. The older was gradle-2.8. Please check in Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle that you have gradle-2.10 if its gradle-2.8 then you first need to get gradle-2.10 and then add it in there.

Comment: what's the version of android studio you are using ? @AllenVork ?

Comment: @jankigadhiya I'm using the newest android studio

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni Mine is already 2.10

Comment: This happends when i update my project's gradle from 1.3.0 to 2.1.0-rc1.But if i create a new project and use 2.1.0-rc1, everything is fine.

Comment: Is there any pre installed version of app is present in your phone.Try uninstalling  it and run it again.Check if it is working or not.I faced the similar problem solved it in this manner.

Comment: It's nothing about the phone. I can't even compile it.

Comment: can you post your root gradle file?